# Diferença entre while e for

Tags: característica-linguagem, while, for, design-de-linguagem

Qual a diferença entre `while` e `for`, se os dois são laços de repetição, se com os dois eu consigo fazer as mesmas coisas tanto condicionar uma parada ou iterações de variável, porque existe os dois. Minha dúvida é:

1. Existe uma forma de demonstrar que um seja melhor que o outro?
2. Existe alguma situação onde somente um atende o caso?

Comment: É uma pena que a resposta aceita não seja realmente de autoria do autor e além de não citar a fonte, não tem a data que foi feita. A informação pode estar defasada. Nos meus testes, não foi isso que aconteceu. Acho que vou responder pelo menos para complementar isto.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Aqui](http://www.linux-kongress.org/2009/slides/compiler_survey_felix_von_leitner.pdf) tem um artigo cientifico que trata só dessa comparação. Além disso, a performance depende claramente da **aplicação** em particular e do **compilador** da linguagem utilizada.

Em `C#`, `FOR` é um pouco mais rápido. `FOR teve uma média de 2,95-3,02 ms`. O `While média de cerca de 3,05-3,37 ms`. Execute você mesmo o código e veja:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int max = 1000000000;
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            if (args.Length == 1 && args[0].ToString() == "While")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("While Loop: ");
                stopWatch.Start();
                WhileLoop(max);
                stopWatch.Stop();
                DisplayElapsedTime(stopWatch.Elapsed);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("For Loop: ");
                stopWatch.Start();
                ForLoop(max);
                stopWatch.Stop();
                DisplayElapsedTime(stopWatch.Elapsed);
            }
        }

        private static void WhileLoop(int max)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i <= max)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(i);
                i++;
            };
        }

        private static void ForLoop(int max)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

        private static void DisplayElapsedTime(TimeSpan ts)
        {
            // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine(elapsedTime, "RunTime");
        }
    }
```

O laço `for` é geralmente usado quando você sabe o número de iterações de antemão. Por exemplo para percorrer um array de 10 elementos que você pode usar para loop e incrementar o contador `0-9` (ou `1 a 10`).
Por outro lado `while` é usado quando você tem uma idéia sobre a faixa de valores em que para fazer uma iteração, mas não sei o número exato de iterações que ocorrem.
por exemplo:

```
while (!algumaCondicao()){
     // Remove elemento (s)
     // Adiciona elemento (s)
}
```

Aqui nós não sabemos exatamente quantas vezes o laço será executado.

Além disso, o `FOR` é mais uma conveniência que um construtor de linguagem. Por exemplo, um `FOR` ser facilmente expandido em um loop while.

`for ( c=0; c<10; c++ )` é equivalente a:

```
c=0;
while ( c<10 ) {
  // alguns códigos loucos aqui
  c++;
}
```

Além disso, O `FOR` não está limitado a operações numéricas simples, você pode fazer coisas mais complexas como esta (sintaxe C):

```
// uma lista encadeada simples
struct node {
  struct node *next;
};
struct node; // declarando nosso nó

//iterar sobre todos os nós a partir do nó 'start' (não declarado neste exemplo)
for ( node=start; node; node=node->next ) {}
```

O resultado é uma iteração sobre uma lista encadeada simples.

Você também pode ter vários inicializadores, condições e instruções (dependendo da linguagem) como tais: `for(c = 0, d = 5; c <10, d <20; c ++, d ++).`

Answer (score 13):

No meu entender, o `for` é açúcar sintático para um caso de uso comum do `while`, que é utilizar uma variável como contador e uma condição baseada no valor dessa variável (ou seja, pare quando a variável chegar em `x`). Em pseudocódigo:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 10) {
   // faz algo
   i++;
}
```

Não sei se dá pra dizer que um é melhor que o outro, mas em casos em que se necessita de um ciclo baseado no valor de um contador, vale mais a pena usar o `for` do que fazer na unha com `while`, simplesmente porque dá menos trabalho e fica mais claro à primeira vista.

Da mesma forma, se você precisa de um loop infinito do tipo `while(true)`, não faz sentido usar um `for`, que é feito para loops finitos. No fundo não faz sentido usar `for` se você não precisa de um contador, já que ele é baseado nisso.

Answer (score 11):

> Existe uma forma de demonstrar que um seja melhor que o outro?

Geralmente o `while` é usado enquanto uma determinada condição não é atendida. Exemplo:

```java
boolean continua = true;
while(continua) {
    //alguma lógica...
    continua = checaSeDesejaContinuar();
}
```

Enquanto o `for` geralmente é usado quando se deseja iterar uma sequência de dados. Exemplo:

```java
int[] notas = new int[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    notas[i] = leProximaNota();
}
```

É claro que é possível fazer um laço de repetição na mão com qualquer um dos dois atingindo o mesmo resultado que se estivesse usando com o outro, mas geralmente existe uma escolha mais apropriada dentre os dois que você alcançará o objetivo com menos trabalho. Exemplo:

```java
boolean continua = true;
for(; continua;) {
    //alguma lógica...
    continua = checaSeDesejaContinuar();
}
```

e

```java
int[] notas = new int[10];
int i = 0;
while(i<10) {
    notas[i] = leProximaNota();
    i++;
}
```

> Existe alguma situação onde somente um atende o caso?

Não. Sempre você conseguirá atingir o mesmo resultado, a diferença é o trabalho que você despenderá para atingí-lo.

Para meios de simplificação de trabalho, em algumas linguagens ainda tem o `foreach` às vezes chamado de `for avançado`.

Exemplo em Java:

```java
int[] notas = new int[]{1, 2, 5, 2, 10};
for(int n: notas) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Exemplo em PHP:

```java
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Já foi dito que a diferença básica é a semântica que você quer dar ao código. Quando o `for` foi inventado ele era mais limitado a dar uma sequência numérica. Quando inventaram de dar mais flexibilidade para ele começou competir mais diretamente com o `while`, embora já competia antes em algumas situações.

Tem linguagem que só tem o `for`. Se pensar bem não precisa mais que isto.

Também foi dito que depende da aplicação, do compilador, mas depende do ambiente também. Pelo menos é isto que explica a conclusão que a resposta aceita chegou (que por sinal foi plagiada [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3629385/221800) já que não cita a fonte). Lá mostrou que o `for` é mais rápido que o `while`. Eu coloquei o código de ambos de forma mais simplificada já que eu não ia medir o tempo. Vou mostrar o código CIL de ambos e não vou falar qual é o `for` e qual é o `while`, tente descobrir. E veja se você encontra qualquer motivo para um ser mais rápido que o outro.

Para ajudar: a instrução `NOP` faz absolutamente nada, não gasta tempo, ela serve para alinhamento ou reserva de espaço para uso posterior, entre outras utilidades.

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0002:  stloc.0
IL_0003:  br.s       IL_000d

IL_0005:  nop
IL_0006:  ldloc.0
IL_0007:  stloc.1
IL_0008:  ldloc.1
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.1
IL_000a:  add
IL_000b:  stloc.0
IL_000c:  nop
IL_000d:  ldloc.0
IL_000e:  ldc.i4     0x2710
IL_0013:  cgt
IL_0015:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0016:  ceq
IL_0018:  stloc.2
IL_0019:  ldloc.2
IL_001a:  brtrue.s   IL_0005

IL_001c:  nop
IL_001d:  ret
```

O outro

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0002:  stloc.0
IL_0003:  br.s       IL_000d

IL_0005:  nop
IL_0006:  nop
IL_0007:  ldloc.0
IL_0008:  stloc.1
IL_0009:  ldloc.1
IL_000a:  ldc.i4.1
IL_000b:  add
IL_000c:  stloc.0
IL_000d:  ldloc.0
IL_000e:  ldc.i4     0x2710
IL_0013:  cgt
IL_0015:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0016:  ceq
IL_0018:  stloc.2
IL_0019:  ldloc.2
IL_001a:  brtrue.s   IL_0005

IL_001c:  ret
```

É claro que isto pode ser diferente em outra linguagem, em outra versão do compilador. Até onde eu sei em C otimizado o código gerado também é igual. A maioria das linguagens na maioria das implementações deve ser assim. Não consigo imaginar porque não seria na maioria das situações.

Até entendo diferenças quando se compara com `foreach`.

[Essa página](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Loops) no WikiBooks pode interessar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Os dois funcionam bem, mas o qual usar vai depender dos seus requisitos.

`for` vai executar as instruções através de uma sequência conhecida `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` - percorrer listas, vetores, executar um número definido `x` de ações e outros.

Enquanto o `while` vai executar as instruções até que a(s) condição(ões) seja(m) atendida(s) `while (check)`.

Em muitos casos você pode fazer a mesma coisa utilizando os 2, por exemplo, um algoritmo que registre os produtos do usuário até que ele insira "fechar" para concluir a compra.

**Exemplo em Java usando `while`**

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> carrinho = new ArrayList<String>();

while (pedido != "fechar") {
    pedido = scan.nextLine();
    carrinho.add(pedido);
}
```

**Exemplo em Java usando `for`**

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> carrinho = new ArrayList<String>();
int i = 0, y = 0;

for (i = 0; y < 10; i++) {
    pedido = scan.nextLine();

    if (pedido == "fechar") {
        break;
    }

    carrinho.add(pedido);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Um `while` é uma forma mais simplista para um laço de repetição, onde em sua estrutura tem-se apenas a condição.

Exemplo:

```
while(condição){
  //Bloco que será executado enquanto condição satisfaça (Ou seja o valor lógico seja true)
}
```

Um `for` é uma estrutura mais complexa do que o `while`. Nesta podemos determinar a inicialização de uma variável. Em seguida, determinamos a condição e, por fim, podemos incrementar uma variável. Geralmente esses três parâmetros estão relacionados:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    /*Este bloco será executado enquanto a variável definida "i" não alcançar o
    número limite estipulado no segundo parametro "i<10" o ultimo parametro 
    trata de incrementar o "i" a cada interação.*/
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente para saber distinguir os dois você necessita sabe quais seus elementos:

#### For

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
    statement

    expr1   =   Executada uma vez incondicionalmente no incio do ciclo
    expr2   =   Avaliado no inicio de cada iteração, se TRUE o loop continua, se FALSE o loop termina
    expr3   =   Executado no final de cada iteração
```

#### Exemplos

```
--------------------------------------------------
for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    #   Inicia a varivel k  (lembrando que ele so executa o 1º argumento 1 vez)
    #   Avalia k
    #   Processa o incremento de k

--------------------------------------------------
int *k; 

for(; k != NULL; k->prox)
    # Note que o 1º argumento foi omitido
    # Avalia k
    # k recebe o próximo ponteiro (lembrando que ele executa sempre no final o 3º argumento)

--------------------------------------------------
for(; (k % 10) != 1;){
    k = rand()%100;

    if((k % 3) == 0){
        k += 27;
    }

    if((k % 2) == 1){
        k += 8;
    }
}

    # Note que o 1º argumento note foi omitido
    # Avalia a expressão
    # Note que o 3º argumento note foi omitido, ou seja o iteração de k depende no contexto do 'for'
--------------------------------------------------
```

#### While

```
while (expr):
    statement
    ...
endwhile;
    expr    =   Avaliado no inicio de cada iteração, se TRUE o loop continua, se FALSE o loop termina
```

#### Exemplos

```
--------------------------------------------------
while(true)
    # Note que a expressão sempre é TRUE, ou seja vai permenecer no while eternamente, 
      a menos que haja um 'break' no meio do 'statement'
--------------------------------------------------
while(false)
    # Note que a expressão é FALSE, ou seja nem vai entrar no while
--------------------------------------------------
int p = 5, k = 3, j = 12;

while(p == 5 && k == 3 || j != 10)
    # Avalia o resultado da expressão
--------------------------------------------------
int p = 5, k = 3, j = 12;

while(p = k - j)
    # Avalia o resultado da expressão
--------------------------------------------------
```

#### Conclusão

`for` lhe fornece recursos para pre-iniciação (executar antes de realizar o laço), validar e processar (ultimo processamento).
`while` lhe fornece o recurso de validar.
Lembrando que ambos sao laços, vai depender de você escolher qual usar,
ate porque qual a diferença entre: `for(;TRUE;)` e `while(TRUE)`?

Answer (score 2):

Tem suas diferenças:

Eu uso o **for** para manipular vetores e **while** quando desejo ficar em um looping até que algo aconteça.