# Dificuldade com laço (repetição) em portugol

Tags: portugol

Tenho esse exercício pra fazer:

> Fazer um programa que solicite ao usuario a quantidade de usinas de
>   energia em uma região, apos ler esta quantidade de usinas, o programa
>   solicita para cada usina qual o tipo de usina (h-hidroeletrica T-
>   termoeletrica E- eolica e qual a potencia gerada, apos lidos os dados
>   de todas as usina o programa contabiliza o total de energia gerado
>   para cada tipo e avalia em qual bandeira a região deve operar. quando
>   mais que 20%  de  nergeia gerada for proveniente de termoeletrica
>   opera-se em bandeira vermelha. quando a geração de termeletrica estver
>   entre 10 e 20 % a região opera em bandeira amarela.

Mas estou com uma dificuldade. Fiz essa parte do codigo, mas não consigo fazer a repetiçao funcionar de forma que se repita ate o número de usinas digitado pelo usuario:

```
algoritmo "semnome"
// Função :
// Autor :
// Data : 08/05/2015

// Seção de Declarações
var nu,cont :inteiro tipo :caractere

inicio

    cont <- 1
    escreval("digite a qtd de usinas")
    leia (nu)
    repita
        escreval("digite o tipo de cada usina ")
        leia(tipo)
    ate (cont = nu)
    // Seção de Comandos

fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Por favor, leia [help] e, principalmente, [ask]. O objetivo do site não é fazer a sua lição de casa. Se você tiver dúvidas específicas sobre o seu problema, em especial a respeito de algo que já tentou (nesse caso, poste a parte do código que já fez!), certamente ajudaremos. Caso contrário, a pergunta estará simplesmente específica demais para ser útil a qualquer outra pessoa além de você.

Comment: após solicitar o numero de usinas, não estou conseguindo fazer a repetição ir ate o numero de usinas especificadas pelo usuario, e essa parte e essencial para conseguir gerir o restante do codigo .

Comment: Você vai perceber que eu editei a sua questão (você poderia ter feito isso sozinho) pra incluir o seu código de exemplo. Fica muito melhor do que nos comentários. Ainda assim, como eu disse, falta você esplicar onde exatamente está com dúvidas. Então, não esqueça de [edit] a questão pra incluir esse tipo de informação.

Comment: Retirei meu voto pra fechar a questão. Por favor, coloque essa explicação da dúvida na questão. :)

Comment: Use um laço para(for) ou enquanto(while), [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61491/91) talvez possa ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem um laço para solicitar o tipo das usinas. Sua condição de controle é:

```
até (cont = nu)
```

sendo `nu` o número de usinas digitados pelo usuário. A variável `cont` é o seu contador do laço, que você corretamente inicializa com 1 em:

```
cont <- 1
```

O problema do seu laço é que *ele não termina nunca*, porque você *não atualiza a variável de controle `cont`*. Para isso, dentro do laço, e como última instrução, incremente em 1 unidade essa variável (para indicar que 1 usina já foi processada):

```
repita
    [...]
    cont <- cont + 1
até (cont = nu)
```

Comment: ok muito obrigado seguir suas instruções e agora ja consigo efetuar o laço corretamente com o controle da variavel.