# Existe alguma diferença entre um loop infinito com for e while?

Tags: php, while, for, loop

No PHP, é possível gerar um *loop* infinito com `while` simplesmente passando o parâmetro `true`.

Exemplo:

```
while (true) {
      echo "Ao infinito e além";
}
```

Também é possível gerar isso através do `for`, simplesmente omitindo os parâmetros, passando os `;`.

Exemplo:

```
 for(;;) {
   echo "Não lembro o desenho que usa a frase acima";
 }
```

Existe alguma diferença funcional entre os dois?

Muda a performance?

Existe alguma vantagem e desvantagem entre um e outro?

Comment: Acredito que por serem loops infinitos, ambos são iguais em questão de performance, mas vamos aguardar alguem com mais conhecimento sobre...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vou responder o óbvio: não muda nada, é gosto.

Do ponto de vista de performance o AP já sabe, não importa.

Mas se quer saber se há uma diferença mínima, parece que tinha em versões antigas, conforme análise feita pelo ircmaxell em sua [ótima resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22917255/221800).

Mudou na versão 5.5 e ficou idêntico. Pode mudar de novo no futuro, ainda que eu duvide.

A maioria das linguagens produzem códigos idênticos neste caso. Tem linguagem que prefere o uso do `for` gerando um *warning* para o `while` tomando partido de qual sintaxe você deveria usar. O `for` desta forma é inequivocamente um *loop* infinito. Com o `while` pode ter acontecido sem querer. É bem verdade que muitas vezes o compilador identifica que existe um `while (true)` depois de otimizações feitas e não estava escrito exatamente isto.

Relacionadas: [Diferença entre while e for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61491/101) e [Como transformar um estrutura while em for? E vice-versa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125714/101)

Answer (score 6):

**Existe alguma diferença funcional entre os dois?**

Não. Única diferença é perante ao design da função, alguns gostam de utilizar `for` outros `while` por ser mais claro e legível o código.

**Muda a performance?**

Não.

Conforme o [PHPBENCH](http://www.phpbench.com/) é possível analisar o benchmark realizado entre o uso dos dois loops:

`%for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i); Total time: 16558 µs`

`$i = 0; while($i < 1000000) ++$i; Total time: 16855 µs`

**Existe alguma vantagem e desvantagem entre um e outro?**

Não.

É por gosto do desenvolvedor, mesmo que atualmente o uso de `while` seja mais constante por causa do design e torna o código mais legível.