# Como funciona o for(;;)?

Tags: loop, sintaxe, for

Provavelmente é duplicada, mas eu não achei aqui no SOpt, e não sei como pesquisar no Google.

Como funciona o laço `for` nessa sintaxe?

```
for(;;)
{
//...
}
```

Comment: Em qual linguagem?

Comment: É a mesma coisa que `while(true) { }`

Comment: A própria pergunta já responde: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90180/101

Comment: Laço infinito. Não inicializa nada, não tem condição de parada, não tem passo incremental

Comment: @Downvoter porque o voto negativo?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nesta forma específica é um *loop* infinito. Só vai parar quando tiver um `break`.

A estrutura de um laço *for*, na maioria das linguagens *mainstream* é a seguinte:

```
for(inicializacao; condicao; pós loop)
```

Onde:

- `inicializacao`:  é um *statement* executado apenas uma vez — antes do primeiro laço. É como um "*pré-for*";
- `condicao` é um *statement* executado **antes de cada loop** e que vai definir se o próximo laço será executado ou não. É como a "condição de parada" das repetições, a partir do momento em que este *statement* retornar `false` as repetições terminam.
- `pós loop` é um *statement* que é executado **após cada laço**.

Qualquer uma destas opções podem ser omitidas, ou seja, podem ser *statements* vazios. Neste caso, o *statement* vai fazer exatamente o que você quer: **nada**.

Comment: Obrigado. Resposta sucinta e eficiente, exatamente o que eu queria