# Qual é a diferença entre os loops infinitos for(;;) e while(true)?

Tags: c++, for, while

**Qual é a diferença entre os loops infinitos `for(;;)` e `while(true)`?**

Há alguma vantagem ou desvantagem de utilizar um ou outro?

Por exemplo, num código simples de validação de entrada no terminal, para validar números int entre 0 e 100:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int valor;
    //For
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "Insira o valor: " << endl; cin >> valor;
        if (valor > 0 && valor <= 100)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Por favor, insira um valor valido: " << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
    //While
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Insira o valor: " << endl; cin >> valor;
        if (valor > 0 && valor <= 100)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Por favor, insira um valor valido: " << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Relacionadas: [Existe alguma diferença entre um loop infinito com for e while?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90180/5878) | [Diferença entre while e for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61491/5878) | [Como funciona o for(;;)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247952/5878)

Comment: Acho mais duplicata desta resposta: [Existe alguma diferença entre um loop infinito com for e while?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90180/existe-alguma-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-um-loop-infinito-com-for-e-while). Do que a marcada como duplicata de for e while comuns... Não tinha achado a outra resposta, pois usei as keywords erradas.