# Quais as diferenças entre as estruturas de repetição enquanto, repita e para?

Tags: loop, portugol

Amigos, estou aprendendo lógica de programação e veio essa dúvida quando eu deveria usar esses comandos e suas diferenças.

Comment: Poderia dar exemplos? A menos que se trate de uma linguagem específica, esses termos (ou seus correspondentes em inglês) às vezes são usados com significados ligeiramente diferentes de linguagem pra linguagem, ficando difícil responder fora de contexto. Se não tiver exemplos, ao menos uma referência de onde você viu esses termos.

Comment: Estou aprendendo logica de programação em portugol.

Comment: Relacionado: [Diferença entre while e for](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61491/91)

Answer (score 7):

**PARA** - Para uma quantidade de repetições já definidas, ou mesmo quando você precisar contar as repetições, e ainda quando você quiser ler um array do ultimo para o primeiro elemento.

**ENQUANTO** - Quando seu código tiver a quantidade de repetições indefinidas e dependendo de uma ou mais condições para parar o laço.

**REPITA** - Quando for obrigatório que o laço rode pelo menos uma vez. O bloco de código dentro do laço vai rodar a primeira vez sem que a condição seja verificada.